# Converting time stamp

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have in issue with this code, I'm reusing it from a different script, it is reading from an xml file and converting the date/time from a node. The date in the node is as follows which is the only difference to the original script:

```
<od>10:15:41 01/03/13</od>
```

I thought I had this modified correctly but it isn't working:

```
$_date=$record->getElementsByTagName("od");
$_date=((!empty($_date))?$_date->item(0)->nodeValue:"");
if(strpos($_date,".")!==false)
{
    $_date=substr($_date,0,strpos($_date,"."));
}
$_date=date("H:i:s m/d/Y",strtotime($_date));
$_date.=(trim($_date)!="")?"Z":"";
xmlrpc_set_type($_date, 'datetime');
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the format in the XML file, how is it different to what you're converting it to? It seems your function should work.

Comment: In order to answer this question we will have to guess what `$record` is. Please show us the relevant XML code.

Comment: The node is <od>10:15:41 01/03/13</od>

Comment: And what are you trying to convert it to? It seems that's already in the right format `H:i:s m/d/Y`

Answer (score 1):

The date/time `10:15:41 01/03/13` is an [invalid format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

`strftime` will work fine with a `Y-m-d H:i:s` format as it's unambiguous.

On the other hand, it gets confused with `H:i:s m/d/y`, as it can be interpreted as `H:i:s d/m/Y`. Think about the date 02/03/2013 - m/d/y would suggest that it's the 3rd of Feb, whereas d/m/Y would suggest that it's 2nd of March.

In other words, to ensure we get the right date every time, we have to be more specific. `date_create_from_format('H:i:s m/d/y', $_date)` will give you a DateTime object corresponding to the correct date, if the date given is indeed in the 'H:i:s m/d/y' format.

```
// Retrieve the date string
$_date=$record->getElementsByTagName("od");
$_date=((!empty($_date))?$_date->item(0)->nodeValue:"");

// Standardize it
$_date = get_date( $_date );
$_date .= (trim($_date) != "") ? "Z" : "";
xmlrpc_set_type($_date, 'datetime');



function get_date( $rawDate ) {

    // Clean date string
    if(strpos($rawDate,".")!==false) {
        $rawDate=substr($rawDate,0,strpos($rawDate,"."));
    }


    // Attempt converting from m/d/y AND m/d/Y formats
    $date = date_create_from_format('H:i:s m/d/y', $rawDate);
    if( false === $date ) $date = date_create_from_format('H:i:s m/d/Y', $rawDate);

    if( !empty($date) ) {
        return $date->format('H:i:s m/d/Y'); // Convert the date to a string again
    }


    // If neither works, try using strtotime instead
    $date = @strtotime($rawDate);
    $date = !empty($date) ? date('H:i:s m/d/y', $date) : false;


    return $date;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, though I get a "Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object"  on "$_date = $_date->format('H:i:s m/d/Y'); // Convert the date to a string again"

Comment: That should do the trick - the date_create_from_format format string ('H:i:s m/d/y') needed a lowercase, rather than an uppercase Y.

Comment: Nope, still throwing the error, I've tried all variations of upper and lowercase and get the error every time

Comment: It won't throw errors any more (fails silently, returning false), and will check both m/d/Y and m/d/y, then use strtotime if neither of the above work. It almost sounds like you might be interpreting the d/m/Y format though, if it keeps throwing errors...